# SqlAlchemy can't find record

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table called `DR` with columns `dag_id`, `execution_date`, and `run_id`. I'd like to find a specific record that I know to exist in the table.

In my unit tests, I create one entry in the table and then try to find it again.

```
tmp = session.query(DR).filter(DR.dag_id == self.dag_id).first()

print(self.dag_id == tmp.dag_id) 
print(self.execution_date == tmp.execution_date)
print(self.run_id == tmp.run_id)
```

All three print statements print true, but then when perform the following query, no records are found:

```
session.query(DR).filter(
    DR.dag_id == self.dag_id,
    DR.execution_date == self.execution_date,
    DR.run_id == self.run_id
).first()
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following query?

```
session.query(DR).filter(
    DR.dag_id == self.dag_id,
    DR.run_id == self.run_id
).first()
```

If that works the problem may be python datetime equality is being evaluated differently to your database datetime equality.

Comment: Good catch, I tried filtering by just `DR.execution_date == self.execution_date` and got no records, so it must be some strange behavior in the date comparison.